# How to sort a vector of pairs by first element?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

I am trying to sort a vector of pairs by the first value in the pair. I've tried to follow the advice of answers to other questions on this that have already been posted but am having trouble getting the vector to sort for some reason. I have tried using std::sort and std::stable_sort to no avail. The code compiles fine and runs with no complaints but the array is not sorted. My sample code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool compare(const std::pair<int, int>&i, const std::pair<int, int>&j){
  return i.first < j.first;
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> vec;
  vec.reserve(10); // reserve space for 10 elements
  int i;
  std::string letters = "abcdefghij";
  int randNum;

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    randNum = std::rand()%(10-0 + 1); // generate random numbers between 0 and 10
    vec[i].first = randNum; // assign random integer to first element of pair
    vec[i].second = letters[i]; // assign letter to second element of pair
  }

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){    // print out unsorted array
    std::cout << vec[i].first << " " << vec[i].second << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare);

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){   // print out sorted array
    std::cout << vec[i].first << " " << vec[i].second << "\n";
  }

  return 1;
}
```

The resulting output looks like so:

```
10 a
1 b
0 c
6 d
8 e
3 f
2 g
0 h
9 i
4 j

10 a
1 b
0 c
6 d
8 e
3 f
2 g
0 h
9 i
4 j
```

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior. The vector has size 0, before, during and after the sort. You are accessing elements past the end of the buffer. Replace `vec.reserve(10);` with `vec.resize(10);`

Comment: Thank you very much, that's solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually resize the vector, your vector is empty.

Instead of:

```
vec.reserve(10);
```

Use:

```
vec.resize(10);
```

This would have been obvious if you had used the range-based for loops:

```
// This won't print anything out at all.
for (const auto &it : vec) {
  std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Or use `reserve` and `push_back`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was indeed the problem. Are range-based for loops the standard way to avoid this kind of issue?

Comment: Range-based for loops are less error-prone than other types of loops, since there are fewer opportunities for typos and mistakes.  Hard-coding the array bounds is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting to learn C++, learn C++11 features. It will make your code easier to write, and less buggy. This is a much better way to write your program, IMO, and it addresses the bug you had. Also, note that return 0 by main means "ok" and 1 means "not ok"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> vec;
  std::string letters = "abcdefghij";

  for(auto l: letters) {
    int randNum = std::rand()%(10-0 + 1); // generate random numbers between 0 and 10
    vec.push_back({randNum, l}); // use constructor to create the pair
                                 // pushback figures it is a pair that must be 
                                 // inserted and calls corresponding constructor (pair 
                                 // in this case)
  } 

  for(auto p: vec) {
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
  }

  std::cout << "\n";

  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto a, auto b) {  // use lambda. Cleaner and easier to read
     return a.first < b.first;
  }); 

  for(auto p: vec) {
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your for loop where you initialize the vector using indexes to push_back.

```
for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        randNum = std::rand() % (10 - 0 + 1); // generate random numbers between 0 and 10
        vec.push_back(std::make_pair(randNum, letters[i])); // assign random integer to first element of pair
                                                            // assign letter to second element of pair
    }
```